# How do I use internal memory as /mnt/sdcard?

Tags: root-access, sd-card, mount

I am using a mobile device which runs Android four and has a broken micro SD card slot. The device also has lots of free internal memory. However for some reason many applications insist on only using /mnt/sdcard or /sdcard (a symbolic link to /mnt/sdcard).

I thought I could fully get around this by utilizing the following command on my **rooted** android:

```
mount -o bind /data/local/tmp/sdcard /mnt/sdcard
```

This was able to trick some applications only. For example the default camera applications that came with my mobile device prompts me to insert an SD card. Furthermore Open Camera reports that it failed to take a picture. MuPDF also prompts me to insert a micro SD card.

With that said how do I "convince" all applications that I "have inserted" an SD card? I have tried searching for questions and using Google but all results I found relate to attempts to use an SD card as internal memory -- the exact opposite of what I want.